# JMeter - Variable set in preprocessor is not available to sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have a relatively simple JMeter test plan setup as shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYsq3.jpg

The relevant part of this is the BeanShell Preprocessor (shown as *Setup element data*) and its relationship to the HTTP Request sampler (shown as *POST /elements*). Both of these are inside a Loop Controller (shown as *Do a few times*).

The Preprocessor gets an array of data stored on the `bsh.shared` object and randomly selects one item. It then sets a variable called `elementTypeId`.

When I run this test, `elementTypeId` gets logged (and I therefore assume is set) correctly. However, the first time around, the variable is not set correctly and still appears as `${elementTypeId}`. Further samples appear to be set but use the n-1th value.

The first, failing sample is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkvvw.jpg

The final sample (and logged values) are shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDwhe.jpg

**Setup element data - BeanShell Preprocessor code:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

Random rand = new Random();
int idx = rand.nextInt(bsh.shared.elementTypes.size());

JsonValue elementType = bsh.shared.elementTypes.get(idx);
String elementTypeId = String.valueOf(elementType.get("id").asInt());
log.info(elementTypeId);
vars.put("elementTypeId", elementTypeId);
```

It looks to me as if the sampler is firing before the preprocessor has set the variable - which seems counter to what *should* be happening.

### Update following UBIK's answer

When I disable the SetQueryParams PreProcessor, it appears that the variable is set correctly (although the request fails as it needs a query parameter to be added).

**SetQueryParams PreProcessor:**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase;

if (sampler instanceof HTTPSamplerBase && 
sampler.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
    // add query parameter to url
    var customPath = sampler.getPath() + '?' + sampler.getQueryString();
    sampler.setPath(customPath);

    // remove query parameter from body
    arguments = sampler.getArguments();
    while (arguments.getArgumentCount() > 1) {
        arguments.removeArgument(arguments.getArgumentCount() - 1);
    }
    sampler.setArguments(arguments);
}
```

Is it possible to have both preprocessors applied to the POST request?

Comment: my first guess would be that on first execution pre-processor has an exception, and thus sets no variable. Did you check jmeter.log?

Comment: Yes. The logs don't show any exceptions. I think UBIK LOAD PACK might be on to something with their answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you issue might be coming from the other PreProcessor :

- SetQueryParams PreProcessor

As per [scoping rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) , this one runs for every HTTP Sampler.

Comment: I tried disabling the SetQueryParams PreProcessor and it appears to be setting the variable correctly - but now I don't have query params on my POST requests. I was hoping that both preprocessors would be applied to the sampler before each request was made.

Comment: You can use many post processor without problem. It's just that here, you're mixing things. What is SetQueryParams aimed at exactly ? Its code is incorrect. I would suggest that you accept this answer and ask a new question to avoid some kind of chatting here.

Comment: So it's not possible to have 2 preprocessor applied to a sampler? I'm not clear on what part of the code is incorrect.

Comment: It is absolutely possible.What is wrong is your manipulation of Arguments of Sampler.

Comment: I have accepted this answer - it is correct that something is wrong with my SetQueryParams PreProcessor. Do you have any further insight into what exactly is wrong about my manipulation of the sampler arguments; it seems to work correctly on its own?

Comment: Reading its code, I don't understand it's use, can you write a new question describing why you need it and showing an example of what it does ?Thanks

Comment: I have actually just solved my problem by removing `sampler.setArguments(arguments) ` - since it's pass by reference, updating the arguments in the preprocessor also updates the sampler's arguments. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Check in console for the exception thrown.
try resolving that

if nothing is working please copy your script, delete Beanshell preprocessor and add BeanShell again and paste your script.
This may be silly but it worked for me.